# Alamofire 5 upload encodingCompletion

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm working with Swift 4 and Alamofire 5, I upload two multibart photos and I want to print the progress

```
 AF.upload(
        multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

            MultipartFormData.append(firstPic, withName: "first_pic", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            MultipartFormData.append(secondPic, withName: "second_pic", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

    }, to: urlString, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                print(totalBytesRead)
            }
            upload.responseJSON { request, response, result in
                print(result)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    })
```

and this gets an error saying

Argument labels '(multipartFormData:, to:, encodingCompletion:)' do not match any available overloads

did the library update the code or something??

Comment: `AF` that's a nice shortcut for Alamofire :)

Comment: @vpoltave Actually it's what Alamofire 5 uses, and yup, it's nice AF :"D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alamofire 5 no longer requires an `encodingCompletion`! Instead, multipart form encoding is done as part of the standard now-asynchronous request process and will return errors on the `Request`, and they're available during `validate` and `response*` calls.

Comment: Thank you my dear, is there an easy way to get uploading progress in alamofire 5?

Comment: `uploadProgress` can be used like the previous `progress`.

Answer (score 18):

Please modify according to your need

```
func upload(image: Data, to url: Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible, params: [String: Any]) {
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
        for (key, value) in params {
            if let temp = value as? String {
                multiPart.append(temp.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            if let temp = value as? Int {
                multiPart.append("\(temp)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            if let temp = value as? NSArray {
                temp.forEach({ element in
                    let keyObj = key + "[]"
                    if let string = element as? String {
                        multiPart.append(string.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    } else
                        if let num = element as? Int {
                            let value = "\(num)"
                            multiPart.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        multiPart.append(image, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }, with: url)
        .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
            //Current upload progress of file 
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            //Do what ever you want to do with response
                if let error = response.error {
                    print(error)
                }
                guard let data = response.value else {
                    return 
                }
                print(value)
        })
}
```

Comment: Where is failure block in this ?

Comment: thanks, it is working for me, but as @VarunNaharia said where can we get an error when network call failed?

Comment: @SohaibSiddique in compilation handler response is Result Type which both contain Value and Error. Please see the update

Answer (score -1):

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]


            AF.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    multipartFormData.append(imageOrVideo!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!, withName: "upload_data" , fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            },
                to: "http://----/new.php", method: .post , headers: headers)
                .response { resp in
                    print(resp)


            }
```